# Optimising the program for large inputs

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Consider this:

```
i=raw_input()
y=int(i.split()[1])
r=raw_input()

for k in range(0,y):
    if raw_input() in r:       #####introduce binary search here
        print "YES"
    else:
        print "NO"
```

This is a very simple program.The inputs would be like:

```
3 1
34 54 36
54
YES
```

The first line is `no of elements in an array` ,`no of queries`

Second line is `array`

Third is `query` which is just asking if element is in `array`.if it is print `YES` else `NO`.
This is a very trivial program.But the problem is when i run this with array of `10000` and `10000` queries the program gives time limit exceeded at one of the sites.

The question is what can i optimize in this?

Solution 1 which i thought was introduce `binary search` but that requires `sorting` which again will take `nlogn` even if fastest is used ie quicksort.

Any ideas????

Comment: As the array elements are hashable, why not put them in a set (`O(n)`) then test membership (`O(1)`)?

Comment: I suggest to use a `set` as a container for `r` that is O(1) for membership checking.

Comment: @vks Is it possible to receive the query previous to the array? May be that way you can search for the query while you read the input. That would be O(n) (There's no better than that because you need to read the whole array).

Comment: Quite bad mcve. x is useless, and you don't explain why the for loop.

Comment: @EricLevieil the for loop if for receiving the `y` number of queries.Thnx for `x` thing.I dont need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
elements, queries = map(int, raw_input().split())
array = set(raw_input().split())  # not really an array, but...
if len(array) != elements:
    raise ValueError('unexpected number of elements in array')
for _ in range(queries):
    print 'YES' if raw_input() in array else 'NO'
```

A [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) has `O(1)` membership testing, so as the elements are hashable (I've chosen to put the strings straight into the set, but you could convert them to integers, which are also hashable) and order doesn't matter you can get a significant speedup.

Note that the number of `elements` isn't really useful in Python, as you can simply take an arbitrary input and `split` it. You could leave out the test against `len(array)` and simply unpack to `_, queries` instead.

Comment: @vks what do you mean *"gets converted to split"*? `split` makes the single string into a `list` of strings, which I have then converted into a `set`. It doesn't really matter if you convert them to `int` or not; `'1' == '1'` just as `1 == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you can improve the lookup time dramatically by creating a `set` form the list of numbers first. But also notice, that you are actually searching strings in strings! For instance, in your example input `34 54 36`, it would also report `YES` for inputs `3` or `4 5`. You should convert both the inputs to `int`. Try this:

```
nums = set(map(int, r.split()))
for k in range(0, y):
    if int(raw_input()) in nums:
        print "YES"
    else:
        print "NO"
```

Also note that you do not actually use the "no of elements in an array" input; not sure whether this is important for grading...